# fixed CHAR_BIT on various systems?

Tags: char, bit, glibc

I am confused about CHAR_BIT in limits.h. I have read some articles saying the macro CHAR_BIT is there for portability. To use the macro not a magic number like 8 in code, this is reasonable. But limits.h is from glibc-headers and it's value is fixed as 8. If glibc-headers is installed on a system on which a byte has more than 8 bits (say 16 bits), is that wrong when compiling? A 'char' is assigned 8 bits or 16 bits?

And when I modified CHAR_BIT to 9 in limits.h, the following code still prints '8', how?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is supplementary:
I've read all replies so for, but still not clear. In practice, `#include <limits.h>` and use CHAR_BIT, I can obey that. But that's another thing. Here I want to know why it appears that way, first it is a fixed value '8' in glibc /usr/include/limits.h, what happens when those systems which has 1 byte != 8 bits are installed with glibc; then I found the value '8' is not even the real value the code is using, so '8' means nothing there? Why put '8' there if the value is not used at all?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is finding a different limits.h than the one you changed. Try commenting out CHAR_BIT and see if you can still compile. If so, you have more than 1 limits.h file.

Comment: @JimRhodes, you mean commenting out `#include <limits.h>`? compile failed. CHAR_BIT undeclared.

Comment: Did you make sure you edited the proper `#ifdef` branch? If you look at any standard library header you will see all sorts of pre-processor branches and `CHAR_BIT` may be defined in dozens of different places. You should never edit these files anyway, they are for reference.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman,  I got it. I commented wrong place.. this time I comment out CHAR_BIT in limits.h, compile success, so it gets CHAR_BIT from other headers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Diving into system header files can be a daunting and unpleasant experience. glibc header files can easily create a lot of confusion in your head, because they include other system header files under certain circumstances that override what has been defined so far.

In the case of `limits.h`, if you read the header file carefully, you will find that the definition for `CHAR_BIT` is only used when you compile code without gcc, since this line:

```
#define CHAR_BIT 8
```

Is inside an `if` condition a few lines above:

```
/* If we are not using GNU CC we have to define all the symbols ourself.
   Otherwise use gcc's definitions (see below).  */
#if !defined __GNUC__ || __GNUC__ < 2
```

Thus, if you compile your code with gcc, which is most likely the case, this definition for `CHAR_BIT` will not be used. That's why you change it and your code still prints the old value. Scrolling down a little bit on the header file, you can find this for the case that you're using GCC:

```
 /* Get the compiler's limits.h, which defines almost all the ISO constants.

    We put this #include_next outside the double inclusion check because
    it should be possible to include this file more than once and still get
    the definitions from gcc's header.  */
#if defined __GNUC__ && !defined _GCC_LIMITS_H_
/* `_GCC_LIMITS_H_' is what GCC's file defines.  */
# include_next <limits.h>
```

`include_next` is a GCC extension. You can read about what it does in this question: [Why would one use #include_next in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261382/why-would-one-use-include-next-in-a-project)

Short answer: it will search for the next header file with the name you specify (`limits.h` in this case), and it will include GCC's generated `limits.h`. In my system, it happens to be `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed/limits.h`.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);
  return 0;
}
```

With this program, you can find the path for your system with the help of `gcc -E`, which outputs a special line for each file included (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)

Because `#include <limits.h>` is on line 2 of this program, which I named `test.c`, running `gcc -E test.c` allows me to find the real file that is being included:

```
# 2 "test.c" 2
# 1 "/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed/limits.h" 1 3 4
```

You can find this in that file:

```
/* Number of bits in a `char'.  */
#undef CHAR_BIT
#define CHAR_BIT __CHAR_BIT__
```

Note the `undef` directive: it is needed to override any possible previous definitions. It is saying: "Forget whatever `CHAR_BIT` was, this is the real thing". `__CHAR_BIT__` is a gcc predefined constant. GCC's online documentation describes it in the following way:

> `__CHAR_BIT__`
>       Defined to the number of bits used in the representation of the char data type. It exists to make the standard header given numerical
>   limits work correctly. You should not use this macro directly;
>   instead, include the appropriate headers.

You can read its value with a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", __CHAR_BIT__);
  return 0;
}
```

And then running `gcc -E code.c`. Note that you shouldn't use this directly, as gcc's manpage mentions.

Obviously, if you change `CHAR_BIT` definition inside `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed/limits.h`, or whatever the equivalent path is in your system, you will be able to see this change in your code. Consider this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", CHAR_BIT);
  return 0;
}
```

Changing `CHAR_BIT` definition in gcc's `limits.h` (that is, the file in `/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed/limits.h`) from `__CHAR_BIT__` to 9 will make this code print 9. Again, you can stop the compilation process after preprocessing takes place; you can test it with `gcc -E`.

**What if you're compiling code with a compiler other than gcc?**

Well, then be it, default ANSI limits are assumed for standard 32-bit words. From paragraph 5.2.4.2.1 in ANSI C standard (sizes of integral types `<limits.h>`):

> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions
>   suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. [...] Their
>   implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude
>   (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> - number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>
>   CHAR_BIT                8

POSIX mandates that a compliant platform have `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Of course, glibc's assumptions can go wrong for machines which do not have `CHAR_BIT == 8`, but note that you must be under an unsual architecture AND not use gcc AND your platform is not POSIX compliant. Not very likely.

Remember, however, that "implementation defined" means that the compiler writer chooses what happens. Thus, even if you're not compiling with `gcc`, there is a chance that your compiler has some sort of `__CHAR_BIT__` equivalent defined. Even though glibc will not use it, you can do a little research and use your compiler's definition directly. This is generally bad practice - you will be writing code that is geared towards a specific compiler.

Keep in mind that you should never be messing with system header files. Very weird things can happen when you compile stuff with wrong and important constants like `CHAR_BIT`. Do this for educational purposes only, and always restore the original file back.

Comment: very detailed and technical explanations! great explanations!

Comment: One correction: "GCC's online documentation describes it in the following way" should be for `__CHAR_BIT__`

Comment: Very detailed explanation. The `gcc -E` method led me to the file `/usr/include/limits.h` that actually contains all the constants defined and because that is the one that is included the last, your environment is set likewise. Interesting to note is that it looks at the `__WORDSIZE` to determine certain values.

Answer (score 6):

`CHAR_BIT` should never be changed for a given system. The value of `CHAR_BIT` specifies size in bits of the smallest addressable unit of storage (a "byte") -- so even a system that uses 16-bit characters (UCS-2 or UTF-16) will most likely have `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Almost all modern systems have `CHAR_BIT == 8`; C implementations for some [DSPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor) might set it to 16 or 32.

The value of `CHAR_BIT` doesn't *control* the number of bits in a byte, it *documents* it, and allows user code to refer to it. For example, the number of bits in an object is `sizeof object * CHAR_BIT`.

If you edit your system's `<limits.h>` file, that doesn't change the actual characteristics of the system; it just gives you an inconsistent system. It's like hacking your compiler so it defines the symbol `_win32` rather than `_linux`; that doesn't magically change your system from Windows to Linux, it just breaks it.

`CHAR_BIT` is a read-only constant for each system. It's defined by the developers of the system. You don't get to change it; don't even try.

As far as I know, glibc only works on systems with 8-bit bytes. It's theoretically possible to modify it so it works on other systems, but without a lot of development work you probably wouldn't even be *able* to install it on a system with 16-bit bytes.

As for why hacking the `limits.h` file didn't change the value you got for `CHAR_BIT`, system headers are complicated, and not intended to be edited in place. When I compile a small file that just has `#include <limits.h>` on my system, it directly or indirectly includes:

```
/usr/include/features.h
/usr/include/limits.h
/usr/include/linux/limits.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/local_lim.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix1_lim.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/posix2_lim.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/predefs.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed/limits.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed/syslimits.h
```

Two of these files have `#define` directives for `CHAR_BIT`, one setting it to `8` and another to `__CHAR_BIT__`. I don't know (and I don't need to care) which of those definitions actually takes effect. All I need to know is that `#include <limits.h>` will give the a correct definition for `CHAR_BIT` -- as long as I don't do anything that corrupts the system.

Comment: @KeithThompson,   thank you for detailed explanations. But I've got more questions... How to understand that the value of CHAR_BIT documents the number of bits in a byte? Does this mean the header is intended for just seeing not for using? It is there only let us know those macro names exist? Changing the value to 9 will not take effect, then why put a number such as '8' there? why just leave it blank?

Comment: @password636: "documents" may not have been the best word. It's primarily intended to be used in code; for example the number of bits in an object is `sizeof obj * CHAR_BIT`. See the third paragraph of my updated answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson, it is for use, but from the practice, the value '8' in /usr/include/limits.h is not what the code (my sample above) uses, because if I change the value to '9' or comment out CHAR_BIT macro definition, the code still can compile successfully. That means value '8' in /usr/include/limits.h doesn't matter, even the whole macro definition there, right? Including <limits.h> is actually leading you the **real** CHAR_BIT definition from some header file. So if its real definition is not there, why putting a CHAR_BIT definition in /usr/include/limits.h? Standards require?

Comment: @KeithThompson, following up, if changing the value or commenting out doesn't matter, what harm can it be to change? It is not even the real CHAR_BIT definition.

Comment: @password636: It can do no good, and could do harm if you happen to modify a file you shouldn't. All you really need to know (and all the language guarantees) is that your C code, if it has `#include <limits.h>`, can refer to `CHAR_BIT and get the correct value.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I can obey the rule in code, no problem, but that's another thing. Here I want to know why it appears that way, it just seems strange to me, first it is a fixed value '8' in glibc /usr/include/limits.h, sure I want to know what about those systems which has 1 byte != 8 bits; then I found the value '8' is not even the real value our code is using, '8' means nothing there? Or something?

Comment: @password636: System headers are complicated (and are not particularly designed to legible for most users). I have no idea why changing the value of `CHAR_BIT` in one file didn't break anything. Maybe the file you changed is used for a different configuration. If you open the hood of your car and hit some random part with a hammer, your car might still run.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I really appreciate your patient replies. But I don't think I got the answer so far. I edited my post, the macro and the way it appears in header file is still mystery to me.

Comment: @password636: The reason CHAR_BIT exists is that there exist some computers where the minimum addressable unit is not an octet.  These are mostly historic mainframes which use 36-bit words and have various character-packings ranging from 5 to 9 bits per character.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit

Answer (score 0):

The whole point is that when compiling for a system with a different size, CHAR_BIT gets changed to the correct size.

Comment: How CHAR_BIT changed? I downloaded and extracted glibc, it is 8 in the extracted limits.h .

Comment: For that system. Do you think it is possible that a glibc for a _different_ system would be different? Why would you use headers for the wrong architecture?

Comment: I mean I downloaded the glibc source and saw it was 8 in limits.h. At this point it is not related to any system, just source text. Does the value get changed to actual number of bits for a byte on the system when I compile glibc? For example, if glibc is compiled on a 9-bit byte system, limits.h will have `#define CHAR_BIT 9`?