# Parse words with strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I want to say to `strtok()` to use as delimeters everything except the alphanumerical characters.

My attempts are the example of the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However I am going to parse real text files (that contain reviews for a site). Currently I check to see what other delimeters occurs and I augment the second argument of `strtok()`. For example, I saw an `[`, so I did it `" ,.-["` and so on, but OK I might miss something and maybe a new text file contain a new delimeter.

Can't I do something smarter (and actually correct, because this is not)?

For example if I get:

`[Hello_sir I'm George]`

I would like to get these tokens:

```
Hello
sir
I
m
George
```

The problem is that I don't know which are the delimeters.

**I would like to say use as delimeters everything except alphanumerical characters.**

---

EDIT

I thought of going character by character and checking if it is alphanumerical, but I was hoping for something built-in, like feeding as desired the `strtok()`.

Comment: maybe you can just use `isalpha` char by char ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/

Comment: Oh yeah I thought about that too, let me update @user2485710

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26243667/971127 To make because there is no.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I need to keep the numbers as well, that's shy I said *alphanumerical*. Do you think that if I pass as second argument to your function `isalnum()` it will be OK?

Comment: @G.Samaras it will be OK.

Comment: Confirmed @BLUEPIXY. I don't see why my question has a point of existence then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that with `strtok` (without overwriting the source string's non-alphanumeric characters with something else) would be to pass a delimiter string which contained all the non-alphanumeric characters. You could build this once at first run-time like this:

```
static char delims[256]; /* this is oversized */

...

void
initdelims()
{
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i<256; i++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(i))
            delims[j++] = i;
    }
    delims[j] = 0; /* this is unnecessary as statics are initialised to zero */
}
```

Then use `delims` as your delimiter string.

However, this is both ugly and inefficient. You would be better writing a hand-rolled parser, borrowing the [source to `strtok`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/string.subproj/strtok.c) if necessary.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking about. However, for portability reasons, you should use `1 << CHAR_BIT` instead of `256`. Also, why this would be "inefficient" – I'm not sure if it even matters. It most probably doesn't.

Comment: `strtok` would for each character iterate through 200-odd characters of the delimiter string. `isalpha` IIRC looks in a fixed bitmap. So `strtok` with a 200-odd character delimiter is likely to be 200 times slower than something hand-rolled, which is not much fun.

Comment: This won't work, I just tested. However, in the comments of the question I got a custom implementation which does exactly what I want so I was thinking that we maybe should delete my question (which can only be done if you delete your answer).

Comment: I think the issue was that i=0 is not alphanumeric so `delims` is empty. Fixed that in the source. Suggest it's worth leaving up for others (if only because they will learn hand-rolling is more useful)

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the non-alphanumeric characters once, in one pass, in one string, then use that string as the delimiter set for `strtok()`:

```
char delims[(1 << CHAR_BIT) + 1] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeof delims - 1; i++) {
    if (!isalnum(i)) {
        delims[j++] = i;
    }
}

pch = strtok(str, delims);
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, delims);
}
```

Comment: Good catch on using `isalnum()`, but notice this about `CHAR_BIT`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708810/fixed-char-bit-on-various-systems. I used 256+1 and the code didn't work.

Comment: I used 256+1 and the code did't work, I just tested. However, in the comments of the question I got a custom implementation which does exactly what I want so I was thinking that we maybe should delete my question (which can only be done if you delete your answer).