# Why do some files in libc++ include_next themselves?

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

I have been looking at the source-code for libc++ and I found a design-pattern that I don't understand: many of the headers `include_next` themselves.

For example, `wchar.h` has on line 17:

```
#include_next <wchar.h>
```

My understanding of [`include_next`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVUN6_1.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp11.zlinux.doc/language_ref/include_next.html) is that it excludes the directory of the current file, so it must be including a different `wchar.h`.

Where is this other `wchar.h` file?

What search-path do I need to add to build libc++?

---

This is not a duplicate of [Why would one use #include_next in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261382/why-would-one-use-include-next-in-a-project) because I am asking about libc++ specifically.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261382/why-would-one-use-include-next-in-a-project

Comment: From the info page: `The use of ‘#include_next’ can lead to great confusion. We recommend it be used only when there is no other alternative.`

Comment: Indeed. I assume the libc++ authors know what they are doing though, and it has been used for a reason.